# What should I do when I find out some company user database I am listed in was leaked?

Tags: email, data-leakage, third-party

Today the antispam tool in the company I work for blocked several emails. It has been months since last time, so I took the time to analyze the quarantined messages.

Since I almost never give my corporate email to outside parties, it is very strange, but last year I participated in an online webinar and since I was watching it at work I used the corporate email.

And the messages seem to be related to the subject of the webinar, what leads me to think the database at the company that held the webinar has been leaked.

Searching google for recent events did not give any news of the leak.

What steps should I do regarding this possible database leak? To protect myself and/or to report the leak in an useful way?

Comment: You first need to confirm it's a leak. If nothing else, the company you took the webinar with sold the list of attendees.

Comment: Did you also give the webinar company a password for an account? Do you use that password for other accounts? If so, change those passwords.

Comment: Consider all the info you provided that company compromised, and if you reused the password anywhere else you should change it (that's why password reuse is bad).

Comment: Try https://haveibeenpwned.com/... Free & easy.  As others mentioned, if you provided this company a password change it, and if you reuse that password elsewhere change those too (and stop reusing passwords!).  Although this incident sounds like marketing spam to me...